# android custom contentprovider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I wrote custom contentprovider that creates a database in sqlite3 with single table 'user_authentication'.

While the db and table have been created on their respective `onCreate()` methods, I am getting an `NullPointerException` in the overriden insert method . Below is the method:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialvalues){
         SQLiteDatabase sqlitedb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         if(sUriMatcher.match(uri)!= TABLE){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown Uri"+uri);
         }

         ContentValues values;
         if(initialvalues != null){
             values = new ContentValues(initialvalues);
         }
         else{
             values = new ContentValues();
         }

         long rowId = sqlitedb.insert(AUTHENTICATION_TABLE_NAME, "", values);

             if(rowId>0){
                 Uri uril = ContentUris.withAppendedId(User.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
                 getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(User.CONTENT_URI, null);
                 sqlitedb.close();
                 return uril;
             }

             throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into User_Authentication : " + uri);


     }
```

While debugging, I see that table is being inserted with the 'values' but when it reaches the `getContext()` it return null and so the error.

I am wondering why the `getContext()` is returing null, becuase the custom contentprovider class extends the  `android.content.ContentProvider`;

Could anyone please help me with this. BTW, I am using 2.3 sdk

Thanks,
Raja Chandra Rangineni

Comment: Is this called after onCreate() was called?

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationContext() should work instead of getContext() .

Comment: Thanks Preethi. I found the cause. I was instantiating a new object for the class that has this insert method. I believe the context is set by dvm when we install the app. I should have used the getContentResolver() which has the context sate initialized by the dvm.  But, I was trying to figure out why cant I access the context or applicationContext from my activity class. Is it the android design behaviour to seperate the business logic from the data aspect? Also, when to use the getContext() vs getApplicationContext()