# Insert failing with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm using a ContentProvider to insert data into a SQLiteDatabase and the insert is failing. I'm hoping someone will see what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    if (uriType != ALLDATA) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI for insert");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        long newID = sqlDB.insertOrThrow(TABLE_BASEPATH,
                null, values);
        if (newID > 0) {
            Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, newID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return newUri;
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Ignoring constraint failure.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

mDB is a global variable which is set up as so:

```
private SQLData mDB;
```

SQLData is the name of my database class. When I follow this code in the debugger, it verifies that newID is greater than 0 and goes into the if block. The first two lines execute (assignment of newUri and getContext() etc) but then the code skips down to the bottom and returns null, instead of returning newUri. Does anyone know why? I've taken a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412259/android-custom-contentprovider), but it doesn't seem to apply to my case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i've had this before and it can be two things.

Firstly, it depends on the debugger. I'm sure i've had it where the code has stepped through the return; statement correctly and only pretends to skip to the return null.

Check the calling function.

Secondly, and usually the culprit in my case. Your running your debugger on an old version of the compiled code. I.e. run a debug clean.

Afraid that i can't remember the exact cause, i just know i've had this exact scenario.

Comment: actually it could be many things, but these are two i check first. Also check that the notifyChange isn't triggering some sort of subsequent call.

Comment: You're right, Emile. The calling function does return a non-null Uri. Weird. So that's not my problem. Thank you!